# PHP open new email message with default mail client

Tags: php, html, email

I want to open an email from a link that is the persons email address, which is displayed in a table with their personal information.

I can 'kind of' get it to work doing this;

```
<a href="mailto:<?php $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?>"><?php echo $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?></a>
```

The new email opens using the default mail client, however the email address is not populated in the 'To:' field, which is really what I am after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you have produces the following:

```
<a href="mailto:">info@example.com</a>
```

Which causes the behavior you're experiencing because the `href` attribute isn't pointing to an actual email address. This is due to the missing `print` or `echo` in the `href` attribute. Your code should look like this, instead:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?>"><?php echo $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?></a>
```

Which will produce:

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
```

And will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Is there any tool I can use to check the html output of my php code? Also is there a way I can achieve the same result using php only?

Comment: @pjmil116 Viewing the page in any browser will check the HTML output of your PHP code: just view the page's source. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "using PHP only".

Comment: Oh I knew that... but thanks for reminding me.

I mean instead of using an <a> tag can I do <?php echo Html->link->... ?> and get the same result. E.g. is there an equivalent 'mailto' function in PHP?

Comment: @pjmil116 `mailto:` is a client-side protocol handler, not unlike `http:`: there is no PHP function for it. You could wrap the HTML into a string and output that instead of using embedded PHP within HTML, but the end result for a web page always is HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

    header("location: mailto:".$person['Person']['primEmail']);

?>
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

YOur code is write...reason for not populating To address is that there is minor issue in your code.. there is no echo in anchor tag...

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?>"><?php echo $person['Person']['primEmail']; ?></a>
```